# Is there a REST API alternative to Set-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy?

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

I am currently working on automating the setting of retention policies of databases within an Azure managed instance. At the moment I am using the Azure `Set-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy` PowerShell Cmdlet. It would be preferable to use REST API for my automation workflow, is there an equivalent?

The retention policy is not part of the  [Managed Instanced - Update API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/managedinstances/update). There is an [equivalent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/backupshorttermretentionpolicies/update) for single instance databases.

Any help in pointing me to an API would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this would be the api call:

```
/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/zzz/databases/uuu/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies/default?api-version=2017-03-01-preview
```

somehow I dont see this in the API reference. But you can always do something like this to figure it out:

```
Set-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy -ResourceGroupName resourcegroup01 -InstanceName server01 -DatabaseName database01 -RetentionDays 35 -Debug
```

and just at the debug output, it will contain REST call url